# Magical Record delete all records Swift

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

I'm trying to clear all rows from a table in Magical Record in Swift. I tried:

```
DeviceLog.mr_truncateAll()
```

but this seems to have no effect. Does someone know how to do it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use this

```
DeviceLog.mr_truncateAll(in: context)
context.mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I wasn't awake, it worked when I do it in save.

```
MagicalRecord.save({ (context) in
            DeviceLog.mr_truncateAll(in: context)
        }, completion: { (changed, error) in
            if let _ = error {
                print("Error truncating DeviceLog: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                print("Truncate DeviceLog successful: \(changed)")
                print(DeviceLog.mr_countOfEntities())
            }
        })
```